# how to convert character to HTML Unicode in php

Tags: php

```
echo "Decode Function:- " . html_entity_decode('&#84;&#69;&#83;&#84');
```

OP:

```
TEST
```

But we need opposite.

```
$title = "TEST";
```

NEED OP:

```
&#84;&#69;&#83;&#84
```

Comment: Use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) then. Did you even research about it?

Comment: No, Actually i am facing issue for developing time in application. I am search google but not getting any function in php. try htmlentities function but not working. Can given me example??

Answer (score 0):

```
$SendMessage = "TEST";

$ArrMsg = str_split($SendMessage);

$Unicode = "";

foreach ($ArrMsg as $key => $value) {
    $code = ord($value);
    $Unicode .=  "&#".$code.";";
}    

$message = $Unicode;
```